# setting a different timeout on groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy

I followed [this post on how to specify a timeout](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/How-to-set-timeout-for-a-request-using-HTTPBuilder-td365903.html), doing:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(restEndpointUrl);
http.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000))
```

and I got the error:

```
Class: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message:No signature of method: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.getParams() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getParser(), getClass(), getHeaders(), getUri()
```

I'm probably setting it on the wrong class but if you directly know what I'm doing wrong your comments are much appreciated.  I'm fairly new to Groovy/Grails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You set the timer on the underlying client ...

```
http.getClient().getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, but the code doesn't work.   I get a "Message: The target server failed to respond within milliseconds of doing a http.request(GET, ContentType.TEXT) after the line you gave me.  I have a println statement on either side of this http.request(..) statement and the println statement after it hits immediately, with the "target server failed to respond error".

Comment: The `.getParams()` method is deprecated, what should we use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm using http-builder 0.7.1 plugin with Grails 2.3.9:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

def timeout = 10000
SocketConfig sc = SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(timeout).build()
RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build()
def hc = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultSocketConfig(sc).setDefaultRequestConfig(rc).build()        
def http = new HTTPBuilder(restEndpointUrl)
http.client = hc
```